# Should I make a method static

Tags: c#, static

I've read a few threads related to the question by I'm still not sure what's better for the current situation. I have two simple classes:

File:

```
string name;
long size;
```

Folder:

```
string name;
IList<File> files;
IList<Folder> folders;
```

If I want to implement a method which calculates the contents **size** of a folder, should I implement it as an instance or as a static member. The implementation needs a Folder object as a sole parameter and it does not change any state of the variable so I'm thinking of making it static but I'm not sure if this is the right step.

Comment: Maybe you should turn this into an answer, @martijnvanput

Answer (score 1):

The most typical, OOP-ish, way to go here is an *instance* method. You shouldn't pass any parameters in but use `this` instead.

Using a `static` method within the `Folder` class itself would be counter-intuitive and possibly break encapsulation principles. The reason is, your method *primarily* operates on a specific `Folder` instance, and no decoupling of the funcionality *away* from the `Folder` class seems to be necessary in such a trivial case. The only valid case would be to support returning a fallback value, such as `0`, in case a `null` reference would be passed in. However, in most cases being tolerant to such inputs causes problems later in the program's control flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can **make a comparison** with something that describe your problem.

> Calculate something when i give you a parameter.

The first thing that comes up in my mind and do a similar thing is [`Math.Pow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a **static method**.

If you want to do `Folder.Size(folder);` than you can make it static.

---

If the method is inside `Folder` the problem is different.

> Calculate something when i have something

The first thing that i think is [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (although this is a property), this is **not static** because this calculate something that is *unique* for every class.

If you want to do `Folder.Size` or `Folder.Size()` than, **non static** is your way to go.

---

**Conclusion:** Use static when a method don't belong to a class.

Answer (score 1):

in this case no, since the size needs a Folder object and you must instantiate one, then add a method like `CalculateSize()` or `GetSize()` inside the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go full OOP and just do it with static.

Comment: Any reasoning behind?